# Is it okay to use snot as a verb?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

The dictionary doesn't list it as a verb. However I get some hits on Google, even on Google Books:

> She heaved and sobbed and **snotted** all over his shirt.

[Source](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22sobbed%20and%20snotted.%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1351&bih=923).

Is it okay to use it as a verb? Or the grammar police will give me the death penalty?

Comment: Yuck.  No. .....

Comment: In the right context it would be perfectly acceptable. In others it would not.

Comment: You might think that's grease on the doorknob, but it's not.

Comment: "Is it okay?" - Primarily Opinion Based. "Is it understandable?" - yes, look up "verbification of nouns".

Comment: It's OK to use any word as any part of speech so long as you are reasonably sure that your audience will A) understand it and B) have a positive reaction to it. Obviously with _snot_ there's an "ick factor" to account for, but even without that: "I need to go _coffee_ up before the meeting" would be fine in an informal context but not so much a formal one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems common among young children (even occasionally as a transitive verb). The rare uses I've heard from adults have been in the context of young children. I don't know what the upper age limit for such use is.

It's a logical formation with no quick alternative learnt later (unlike some things little ones come out with) so it's quite likely to stick around. It wouldn't surprise me if your quoted use and many other Google hits were young adult books.

Kids can be very creative in their use of language, in ways that aren't a good idea to copy if you're an adult.

Comment: To put it another way it's better to use *snot* as a verb than an adhesive

Answer (score 1):

Snot (verb, transitive, informal) To punch on the nose sufficiently hard to draw blood.
EXAMPLE: Some stranger started abusing me outside the nightclub, so I just snotted him.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting answer and welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. A link to your reference will improve your answer.